# Row data field will be lost if value is undefined after JSON.stringify() in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I found that an issue in the .net server side development.

.net method like this:

```
<Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)> Public Function fn_save(ByVal data As String)
```

Frontend js will call this method

```
fn_save(JSON.stringify(cell.getData()))
```

fn_save method only receive a string. So I have to stringify the row data. And it should be ok as normal.

But, if no value in the field(no edit or clear etc.), this field value will be undefined, and it looks like below.

```
JSON.stringify({content: undefined}); // return {} after stringify
```

So for this scene, I have to loop through the object and change undefined to an empty string or something else.

Should I do like this? Or the default value will change to `null` instead of `undefined`? Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

setting a value to undefined is not valid in JSON, which is why it is missing in the object when you stringify it.

If you have the data as an array of objects this can be passed directly into Tabulator with no need to stringify it in the first place

If a column is missing in row data, Tabulator just sets it to an empty value, and keeps on going, it shouldnt cause any issues in the rendering of your table

Comment: Yes, I know it works no need to stringify the row data in php, but our backend developer told me that I have to stringify it, because they can only use string in .net method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If a column is missing in row data tabulator just sets it to an empty value, and keeps on going, it shouldnt cause any issues in the rendering of your table

Comment: Yes, so I loop through the row data and replace emtpy string to undefined.

Comment: You shouldnt need to replace anything, it will just work. Not all fields need to be defined on a rows data object, Tabulator can cope without them

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a loop there like below ,this will be simple way to overcome this limitations

```
var string = 
JSON.stringify(EditedData,function(k, v){return v === undefined ? null : v;});
```

this should work fine and any empty field will be accepted in your back end